# Nodes as a pointer

Tags: c, data-structures

Why the nodes in a linked list are declared as pointers? Nodes contains the pointer part in it to link to another node. Then why the nodes are itself a pointer?

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *link;
} *start;
```

Now we introduce nodes as

```
struct node *tmp;
```

Now this is a node which is a pointer to data type struct node..but for linking we use the link pointer to link the other node
Why dindnt we coded node as

```
struct node tmp;
```

only...is this because of allocating dynamic memory..or something more?

Comment: The nodes are structs, not pointers. Maybe you should show an example of what you mean.

Comment: Each node knows where the next node is located in memory; to store this information it uses a pointer. No other approach is possible because a struct cannot contain a member of its type (how would you calculate its size then?), but can store a _pointer_ to an object of its type.

Comment: Struct node             
{
Int data;
Struct node *link;
}*start;
Now we introduce nodes as
Struct node *tmp;
Now this is a node which is a pointer to data type struct node..but for linking we use the link pointer to link the other node
Why dindnt we coded node as
Struct node tmp ;
only...is this because of allocating dynamic memory..or something mor

Comment: Please put your code etc *in the question*.

Comment: Why? Because you only want *one copy* of each node, otherwise you'll have to keep track of, and keep updated, all the copies you have. So that's one reason the pointers are used, pointing to the one copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is because the nodes are allocated dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

struct node tmp could be using tmp as a dummy or sentinel node, where it's data is not used, only it's next pointer to the actual first node of a list.

struct node *tmp would be using tmp as a pointer to the first node of a list or as a working pointer to some node in a list when scanning a list.

In some cases a list structure is also used:

```
struct list{
    struct node *head // pointer to first node
    struct node *tail // optional: pointer to last  node
    size_t size;      // optional: number of items in a list
}
```

A circular list could be implemented using just a tail pointer to the last node, which in turn would have a next pointer to the head/first node.