# Nodes data type

Tags: c, data-structures

Why the nodes in a linked list are declared as pointers? Nodes contains the pointer part in it to link to another node. Then why the nodes are itself a pointer?

```
struct node 
{ 
    int data; 
    struct node *link; 
} *start;
```

Now we introduce nodes as

```
struct node *tmp;
```

Now this is a node which is a pointer to data type struct node..but for linking we use the link pointer to link the other node Why dindnt we coded node as

```
struct node tmp;
```

only...is this because of allocating dynamic memory..or something more?

Comment: OP asked the same question a half hour ago. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33764976/nodes-as-a-pointer

Comment: Can u tell me whats node are pointing to?

Comment: Pointing to another node.

Comment: That is the link part of node pointing to another node.

Comment: Nodes are itself a pointer what does it points to?

Comment: Can u please comment on node tmp declration in the question?

Comment: `struct node tmp;` defines a variable called `tmp` which is a structure of type `struct node`. But `struct node *tmp;` defines a *pointer* variable to a structure of type `struct node`. This pointer has not been initialised, so currently does not point to anything you can access. It has to be initiliased either with `NULL` as a marker (so the program knows it has not yet been set to a valid address), or with the address of a `struct node` variable.

Comment: The short answer is a pointer has the flexibility required to make a list work. With a pointer, you can either allocate memory and hold the start address to the block with a pointer, or, you can assign the address of another block to it. While you create a block of memory for a node that is held by one pointer, you have allocated space for the *next* pointer that is assigned the address of the *next* node. So the *node* pointer points to storage for the current node and *next* points to storage for the *next* node and so on and so forth creating the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nodes in linked lists in C always allocated in a heap to allow you manage their lifetime. Therefore for creating, destroying and adding nodes to list, you need to declare a pointer on a node:

```
struct node *tmp; // declaring
tmp = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node)); // creating (allocating memory)
// ... tmp initializing and processing
free(tmp); // removing (freeing memory)
tmp = NULL;
```

Otherwise, if you create a node on stack `node tmp;`, it's lifetime will be managed by the rules of language, not by your business logic.

Comment: ok i got you. We are doing this for dynamic memory allocation